# creating an array in another method

Tags: arrays

```
private String[] items;
private int numItems;

public SortedListArrayBased()
{
    items = null;
    numItems = 0;
}
```

this is my constructor, but in the next method i would like to create an array with values in it like this

```
if( numItems == 0 )
{
    items[0] = temp;
    numItems++;
}
```

when i run, it tells me null pointer which i think is because the array has no space in it from the constructor, is there a way to reinitialize my array in the second method. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public SortedListArrayBased()
{
    items = null;
    numItems = 0;
}
```

to

```
public SortedListArrayBased()
{
    items = new String[];;
    numItems = 0;
}
```